# Calculate the sum of absolute difference of a column over two adjacent days on id

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        day=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],
        id=[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4],
        value=[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2, 7, 3, 5, 3, 4],
    )
)
```

I want to calculate the sum of absolute difference of 'value' column between every two consecutive days (ordered from smallest to largest) matched by id and treat null/None/unmatched as 0. To be more specific, the result for day 1 and 2 can be calculated as:

```
Note  id: 1     id: 2     id: 3     id: 4   -- difference for each id (treat non-existent as 0)
     (1 - 0) + (3 - 2) + (5 - 2) + (2 - 0) = 7
```

And, the final result for my example should be:

```
day res
1-2 7
2-3 9
3-4 9
4-5 16
```

How can I achieve the result I want with idiomatic pandas code?

Is it possible to achieve the goad via groupby and some shift operations? One challenge I have with shift is that non-overlapping ids between two days cannot be handled.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot the dataframe to reshape then calculate the sum of abs diff

```
p = df.pivot('id', 'day', 'value').fillna(0)

# day    1    2
# id           
# 1    1.0  0.0
# 2    2.0  3.0
# 3    2.0  5.0
# 4    0.0  2.0

sum(abs(p[1] - p[2]))
# 7
```

---

To calculate sum of abs diff's between multiple days

```
p = df.pivot('id', 'day', 'value').fillna(0)

# day    1    2    3    4    5
# id                          
# 1    1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  5.0
# 2    2.0  3.0  2.0  7.0  0.0
# 3    2.0  5.0  0.0  3.0  3.0
# 4    0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  4.0

s = p.diff(axis=1).abs().iloc[:, 1:].sum()

# day
# 2     7.0
# 3     9.0
# 4     9.0
# 5    16.0
# dtype: float64

s.index = [f'{x}-{y}' for x, y in zip(p.columns[:-1], p.columns[1:])]

# 1-2     7.0
# 2-3     9.0
# 3-4     9.0
# 4-5    16.0
# dtype: float64
```

---

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works for my example. But if the real data have more days than just two, could your solution generalize to that case? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate? what would be the expected output in such case?

Comment: a dataframe with two columns - day and result, such as between day 1 and day 2, the result is 7; between day 2 and day3, the result is whatever the result is, and so on.

Comment: I updated my question as well to make it more clear. Also, if it can be achieved via groupby, it would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: Check the update. I would prefer pivot in this case since its much simpler